# - vs -= operators with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having some strange behavior in my python code related to `-` and `-=`. I'm writing a QR decomposition using numpy, and have the following line of code in a double loop:

```
v = v - r[i,j] * q[:,i]
```

where `q` and `r` are both `numpy.array`, and `v` is a slice of another `numpy.array` taken as `v = x[:,j]`.

The above code doesn't work as expected in all cases. However, if I make the following change:

```
v -= r[i,j] * q[:,i]
```

Then everything works flawlessly.

I was under the impression that those two lines should be identical. To test whether `-=` and `_ = _ -`  were working differently, I created the following snippet

```
import numpy

x = numpy.array(range(0,6))
y = numpy.array(range(0,6))

u = x[3:5]
v = y[3:5]

print u,v

u = u - [1,1]
v -= [1,1]

print u,v
```

which again works as expected, producing `[2 3] [2 3]` at both print statements.

So I'm entirely confused why those two lines perform differently. The only possible thing I can think of is that I am dealing with extremely small numbers sometimes (on the order of 10^-8 or smaller) and there is some precision issue that `-=` is better at? The first line performs increasingly worse as the elements of `x` get smaller.

I apologize if there's any other posts about this similar issue, I can't search for `-` and `-=` and I don't know if there's any correct terms for these besides assignment/operators.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For future reference if you want to search for stuff like this the names for `-` and `-=` are [`__sub__`][1] and [`__isub__`][2] respectively.  So:

`a = a - b` is equivalent to `a = a.__sub__(b)`

`a -= b` is equivalent to `a.__isub__(b)`. (unless __isub__ is undefined, then it falls back on the above)

  [1]: http://pyref.infogami.com/__add__
  [2]: http://pyref.infogami.com/__iadd__

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When `v` is a slice, then `v -= X` and `v = v - X` produce very different results. Consider

```
>>> x = np.arange(6)
>>> v = x[1:4]
>>> v -= 1
>>> v
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> x
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5])
```

where `v -= 1` updates the slice, and therefore the array that it views, in-place, vs.

```
>>> x = np.arange(6)
>>> v = x[1:4]
>>> v = v - 1
>>> v
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> x
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

where `v = v - 1` resets the variable `v` while leaving `x` untouched. To obtain the former result without `-=`, you'd have to do

```
v[:] = v - 1
```

Comment: super helpful, thanks. Could it be changed to v-=100 ? Had to look a couple of times to see the difference...

Answer (score 14):

You could get different results from `x - y` and `x -= y` if the data types of `x` and `y` differ.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(range(0,6))
y = np.array(np.arange(0,3,0.5))

print x - y
x -= y
print x
```

This prints out:

```
[ 0.   0.5  1.   1.5  2.   2.5]
[0 0 1 1 2 2]
```

It may be worth making sure your arrays' `dtypes` are exactly as you expect (e.g. you're not inadvertently using integer or `float32` arrays instead of `float64`), paying particular attention to arrays used on the left-hand side of `-=`.

Comment: +1 even if this turns out not to be the reason; I'd overlooked that possibility entirely, and shouldn't have.

Answer (score 5):

+1 to both other answers to this questions. They cover two important differences between `=` and `-=` but I wanted to highlight one more. Most of the time `x -= y` is the same as `x[:] = x - y`, but not when `x` and `y` are slices of the same array. For example:

```
x = np.ones(10)
y = np.ones(10)

x[1:] += x[:-1]
print x
[  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.]

y[1:] = y[1:] + y[:-1]
print y
[ 1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
```

Comment: That is incredibly wonky. Can you explain how the first result comes about?