# Are numpy arrays passed by reference?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I came across the fact that `numpy` arrays are passed by reference at multiple places, but then when I execute the following code, why is there a difference between the behavior of `foo` and `bar`

```
import numpy as np

def foo(arr):
   arr = arr - 3

def bar(arr):
   arr -= 3

a = np.array([3, 4, 5])
foo(a)
print a # prints [3, 4, 5]

bar(a)
print a # prints [0, 1, 2]
```

I'm using python 2.7 and numpy version 1.6.1

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9047111/166749

Comment: This thing Python calls "references" has nothing to do with pass-by-references, that's why.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

In Python, [all variable names are references to values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

When Python evaluates an assignment, [the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order). `arr - 3` creates a new array; it does not modify `arr` in-place.

`arr = arr - 3` makes the local variable `arr` reference this new array. It does not modify the value originally referenced by `arr` which was passed to `foo`. The variable name `arr` simply gets bound to the new array, `arr - 3`. Moreover, `arr` is local variable name in the scope of the `foo` function. Once the `foo` function completes, there is no more reference to `arr` and Python is free to garbage collect the value it references. [As Reti43 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585793/are-numpy-arrays-passed-by-reference/11585878?noredirect=1#comment56288437_11585878), in order for `arr`'s value to affect `a`, `foo` must return `arr` and `a` must be assigned to that value:

```
def foo(arr):
    arr = arr - 3
    return arr
    # or simply combine both lines into `return arr - 3`

a = foo(a)
```

In contrast, `arr -= 3`, which Python translates into a call to the [`__iadd__` special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__isub__), does modify the array referenced by `arr` in-place.

Comment: And therefore, in order for `foo()` to have an effect, it needs to return `arr` and in the code you run it as `a = foo(a)`.

Comment: Wait so are objects passed by reference to functions in python...?

Comment: Python does not pass-by-reference nor pass-by-value. Some call it [call-by-object](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm). See also this [footnote in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#id2).
Since that term is not well known, it is important (and necessary) to [describe it](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) as well as to name it.

Comment: See also [How do I write a function with output parameters (call by reference)?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference), and [here for more on call-by-object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing).

Answer (score 11):

Python passes the array by reference:

```
$:python
...python startup message

>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.zeros((2,2))
>>> x
array([[0.,0.],[0.,0.]])
>>> def setx(x):
...    x[0,0] = 1
...
>>> setx(x)
>>> x
array([[1.,0.],[0.,0.]])
```

The top answer is referring to a phenomenon that occurs even in compiled c-code, as any BLAS events will involve a "read-onto" step where either a new array is formed which the user (code writer in this case) is aware of, or a new array is formed "under the hood" in a temporary variable which the user is unaware of (you might see this as a `.eval()` call).

However, I can clearly access the memory of the array as if it is in a more global scope than the function called (i.e., `setx(...)`); which is exactly what "passing by reference" is, in terms of writing code.

---

And let's do a few more tests to check the validity of the accepted answer:

```
(continuing the session above)
>>> def minus2(x):
...    x[:,:] -= 2
...
>>> minus2(x)
>>> x
array([[-1.,-2.],[-2.,-2.]])
```

Seems to be passed by reference.  Let us do a calculation which will definitely compute an intermediate array under the hood, and see if x is modified as if it is passed by reference:

```
>>> def pow2(x):
...    x = x * x
...
>>> pow2(x)
>>> x
array([[-1.,-2.],[-2.,-2.]])
```

Huh, I thought x was passed by reference, but maybe it is not?  -- No, here, we have shadowed the x with a brand new declaration (which is hidden via interpretation in python), and python will not propagate this "shadowing" back to global scope (which would violate the python-use case: namely, to be a beginner level coding language which can still be used effectively by an expert).

However, I can very easily perform this operation in a "pass-by-reference" manner by forcing the memory (which is not copied when I submit x to the function) to be modified instead:

```
>>> def refpow2(x):
...    x *= x
...
>>> refpow2(x)
>>> x
array([[1., 4.],[4., 4.]])
```

And so you see that python can be finessed a bit to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 9):

The first function calculates `(arr - 3)`, then assigns the local name `arr` to it, which doesn't affect the array data passed in. My guess is that in the second function, `np.array` overrides the `-=` operator, and operates in place on the array data.