# How to replace an element of a replicate array without disturbing the original one?

Tags: python, numpy

I am kind of a newbie in python and this puzzles me for a while.

I wrote the code below:

```
pool = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])

def ringDisc(data):
    data_new = data
    data_new[1] = 0
    return data_new

print(pool)
print(ringDisc(pool))
print(pool)
```

I expect the result should be `[[1,1],[1,1]]` for the first "print" and `[[1,1],[0,0]]`for the second "print" and `[[1,1],[1,1]]` for the last.

But what I got from this is `[[1,1],[1,1]]`; `[[1,1],[0,0]]`; `[[1,1],[0,0]]`.

could anyone help me with this and explain why my code doesn't work out in the way I want? thank a lot!

Comment: For the "Why this happens" (which is not very intuitive and actually quite a complex issue under-the-hood): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585793/are-numpy-arrays-passed-by-reference

Comment: In python, `pool`, `data`, `data_new` all reference the same object.  None of the steps makes a copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
data_new = np.copy(data)
```

Inside `ringDisc`

So with this change, the code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

pool = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1]])


def ringDisc(data):
    data_new = np.copy(data)
    data_new[1] = 0
    return data_new


print(pool)
print(ringDisc(pool))
print(pool)
```

The result:

```
[[1 1], [1 1]]
[[1 1], [0 0]]
[[1 1], [1 1]]
```

As expected.

Comment: No problem! Glad that this helped you.

Comment: @Veronica If that solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer or any other answer that solved your problem by clicking the "tick" button next to the corresponding answer.

Answer (score 0):

In numpy views and copy are two different concept, in your case you want to modify a copy of your data. [An interesting article about that](https://www.jessicayung.com/numpy-views-vs-copies-avoiding-costly-mistakes/).

### As mentioned by @Rafael, you could do somehting like this.

```py
pool = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])

def ringDisc(data):
    data_new = np.copy(data) # <===== Here 
    data_new[1] = 0
    return data_new

print(pool)
print(ringDisc(pool))
print(pool)
```

Comment: @GPhilo When I have writen this awnser, existing code was not yet there ! @Rafael only put `data_new = np.copy(data)` as an awser. I have also upvote its awser.