# Numpy array indexing with complete vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, softmax, cross-entropy

What does the following code do? (`grad[range(m),y] -= 1`)

```python
def delta_cross_entropy(X,y):
    """
    X is the output from fully connected layer (num_examples x num_classes)
    y is labels (num_examples x 1)
        Note that y is not one-hot encoded vector. 
        It can be computed as y.argmax(axis=1) from one-hot encoded vectors of labels if required.
    """
    m = y.shape[0]
    grad = softmax(X)
# What does this do? Does it subtract y from grad? (As that is what is supposed to happen)
    grad[range(m),y] -= 1
    grad = grad/m
    return grad
```

**EDIT:** This is not about how slices update the arrays they are from inplace, as `y` is not a slice of `grad`, this question is about the syntax of NumPy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [- vs -= operators with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047111/vs-operators-with-numpy)

Comment: Feel free to edit the title, or tell me, what the correct search term would be, because i am unsure my title fits the bill perfectly

Comment: @alex Kind of, but i still do not understand what it does ... sry

Comment: it subtracts 1 from a subset of elements of `grad`.  The indexing determines which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grad[range(m),y] -= 1 # It is the same as subtracting X[i,j] when j==y[i].
```

Comment: I just realised, that X is a matrix, in my case x was always just a vector. 
PLease correct me if a am wrong, but does this mean, that in `grad`, every column will get `y` subtracted from it?

Comment: Yes exactly as you said.